# Apache POI Creating excel file from existing excel file taking too long

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am creating an excel file from an existing excel file with some changes in the new file like adding logo to header, changing print-related formatting. I am using Apache POI version 3.15. I am working with xlsx file. The existing file has 757 rows and 47 columns, file size is 294KB. The resulting file is 630KB. But it's taking about 5 minutes. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Here is the approach and code I am using:

1. Open the template file for output (takes negligible time)

   ```
   File file = new File("templateName.xlsx");
   workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
   ```
2. Open the existing file (takes negligible time)

   ```
   File file = new File("inputFile.xlsx");
   xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
   ```
3. Copy all the cells from existing worksheet to the new worksheet along with the cell styles. It also handles merged cells and repeated headers in all pages (takes about 1 minute time)

   ```
   private void copyData(XSSFSheet from, boolean repeatRow){
   int length =  from.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
   System.out.println("Copying " + length + " lines of data...");
   int maxNumOfCols = 0;
   int numOfCols;

   CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

   // Get header-footer related data
   getHeaderFooterData(from);
   // Set header footer
   setHeader(headerLeft, headerCenter);
   setFooterWithDateString(footerLeft, "Page", "of");

   XSSFRow dataRow, destRow;
   XSSFCell cell;
   for(int i=ROW_OFFSET, r=0; i<length; i++, r++){
       dataRow = from.getRow(i);
       if(dataRow == null) continue;

       destRow = sheet.createRow(r);
       destRow.setHeight(dataRow.getHeight());
       //System.out.println("Height of row " + i + ":" + dataRow.getHeightInPoints());
       /*
       XSSFCellStyle rowStyle = destWorkbook.createCellStyle();
       rowStyle.cloneStyleFrom(dataRow.getRowStyle());
       destRow.setRowStyle(rowStyle);
       */

       numOfCols = dataRow.getLastCellNum();
       if(numOfCols > maxNumOfCols)
           maxNumOfCols = numOfCols;

       for(int j=0; j<numOfCols; j++){
           cell = from.getRow(i).getCell(j);
           if (cell!=null) {
               XSSFCell destCell = destRow.createCell(j);

               // Copy style from old cell and apply to new cell
               XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
               cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(cell.getCellStyle());
               destCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

               // If there is a cell comment, copy. No comments for our case
               /*
               if (cell.getCellComment() != null) {
                   System.out.println("Added cell comment");
                   destCell.setCellComment(cell.getCellComment());
               }
               */
               // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
               if (cell.getHyperlink() != null) {
                   XSSFHyperlink link = (XSSFHyperlink) createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
                   link.setAddress(cell.getHyperlink().getAddress());
                   link.setTooltip(cell.getHyperlink().getTooltip());
                   destCell.setHyperlink(link);
               }

               // Set the cell data type
               destCell.setCellType(cell.getCellType());

               switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                   case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                       destCell.setCellValue(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                       break;
                   case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                       if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                           destCell.setCellValue(cell.getDateCellValue());
                       }else {
                           destCell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                       }
                       break;
                   case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                       destCell.setCellValue(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                       break;
                   case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                       //destCell.setCellValue("");
                       break;
                   case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                       destCell.setCellErrorValue(cell.getErrorCellValue());
                       break;
                   case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                       destCell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula());
                       break;
                   default:
                       destCell.setCellValue(cell.getRawValue());
                       break;
               }

           }

       }
   }

   // set column widths
   System.out.println("maxNumOfCols: " + maxNumOfCols);
   for(int w=0; w<=maxNumOfCols; w++)
       sheet.setColumnWidth(w, from.getColumnWidth(w));

   // Process merged cells
   for(int i=0; i<from.getNumMergedRegions(); i++){
       //System.out.println("Merging cells");
       CellRangeAddress region = from.getMergedRegion(i);
       // ignore any merged region in the header/footer data section which is upto the ROW_OFFSET
       if(region.getFirstRow() < ROW_OFFSET)
           continue;
       region.setFirstRow(region.getFirstRow() - ROW_OFFSET);
       region.setLastRow(region.getLastRow() - ROW_OFFSET);
       sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
   }

   // set repeating header row if applicable
   String range = "" + String.valueOf(headerRowIndex-ROW_OFFSET) + ":" + String.valueOf(headerRowIndex-ROW_OFFSET);
   if(repeatRow){
       sheet.setRepeatingRows(CellRangeAddress.valueOf(range));
   }
   ```

   }
4. Write the resulting workbook to a new file (takes about 4 minutes time)

   ```
   FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("newFileName.xlsx");
   workbook.write(outputStream);
   ```

Comment: do you have to use POI absollutally to save the file?

Comment: I have to use POI for excel generation. Is there any other way, I can save XSSFWorkbook?

Comment: What about `workbook.close()`? Or at least closing the `outputStream`? And since you are using a `File` to open `xssfWorkbook` do also `xssfWorkbook.close()` when you do not need this workbook further. And you should use `WorkbookFactory.create(file)`. But if really the writing process is the most time consuming process, then mostly there is a problem with the storage location. So where (on what kind of storage location) are you creating and writing the new file?

Comment: @AxelRichter I am writing the file to the disk. Moreover, one of the bottlenecks, I feel like is creating a new CellStyle for each cell from the existing one. Let's say for example, the existing excel file has 50 different cell styles in a sheet with 500 cells. But in the new sheet where I copied the data will have 500 cell styles (because of `XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(cell.getCellStyle());
            destCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);`). How can I limit the number of cell styles to 50 in this case? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a few things and they improved the run time. Here are the things I did:

- Closed the workbooks and file streams once I am done with it according to  Axel Richter's suggestion. Thanks Axel!
- Moved the merging cell process to the top instead of the bottom
- Reused cell style by using a Hashmap instead of creating cell style for each cell in the workbook. The following code shows how I did this:

  ```
  HashMap<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> cellStyleMap = new HashMap<Integer, XSSFCellStyle>();
  // create the cell style only if it is not already there
  int styleHashcode = cell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
  XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = cellStyleMap.get(styleHashcode);
  if(cellStyle == null) {
       cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
       cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(cell.getCellStyle());
       cellStyleMap.put(styleHashcode, cellStyle);
  }
  destCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
  ```